# find windows files with same base name and copy

Tags: powershell-3.0

kind of new to powershell - I have a folder where an index file (*.txt like 1234.txt) with associated pdf files (1234.pdf or 1234_2.pdf)  what are powershell commands to find the similar base names and moving them to another folder(numeric part of the file names will change each time for each group of files)
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

You can use simply use `Move-Item /path/to/files/basename.* /target/path/`

For some advanced solution you can use [Get-ChildItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) and [Where-Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) with `Basename`

Answer (score 0):

Enumerate the .txt files, then move all files `<basename>*.pdf` for each .txt file:

```bsh
$src = 'C:\some\folder'
$dst = 'C:\other\folder'
Get-ChildItem -Path $src -Filter '*.txt' | ForEach-Object {
    Move-Item -Path ($_.FullName -replace '\.txt$', '*.pdf') -Destination $dst
}
```